# Install MongoDB on a virtual machine running CentOS Linux in Windows Azure

Tags: linux, bash, mongodb, azure, virtual-machine

Primary Content Reference: 
"http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-mongodb-virtual-machines-linux-install-centos/"

Beginner at linux cmd and MongoDB on Virtual Machines here.

The Tutorial: Install MongoDB on a virtual machine running CentOS Linux in Windows Azure

Is an easy follow until you reach

The Section: Install and run MongoDB on the virtual machine

As someone use to using a x64 Win8 OS I am completely lost on how I am suppose to bypass the permission denial that won't allow me to `touch 10gen.repo` or `sudo yum install mongo-10gen mongo-10gen-server`. Can someone please respond with a ELI5 format?

Related Resources:
"https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104916/how-do-you-configure-package-management-system-yum-for-mongodb"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the repository file with sudo as well.

Try this:

```
$ echo "[MongoDB]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/yum.repos.d/10gen.repo

$ sudo yum update
```

And then:

```
sudo yum install mongo-10gen mongo-10gen-server
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Worked perfectly! I'm going to link this answer on a couple of websites. Do you have a blog you'd like to link?

Comment: The 'blog' you should link to is MongoDB's tutorial for Amazon EC2 instances: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/ ;)

Comment: Self-promoting link recommendation that is Azure-specific with a script to help: http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2013/09/mongodb-azure-linux/